# Laravel - edit pdf with FPDF with a soruce file from s3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, fpdf

Im working on a Laravel backend and I need to edit a PDF file allocated in a s3 bucket. When I try opening the PDF with `$pdf->setSourceFile($url)` I get an error saying `Given stream is not seekable!`

I can get the file contents using `Storage::disk(ENV('FILESYSTEM'))->url($url);`, and return it to the front end and that works fine, so I know the path and the permissions are correct. I would like to the content to the `setSourceFile($contents)` method, intead of the url. is there any way to do this?

By the way, Im using the Laravel filesystem

**Edit**: I have tried copying the file from s3 to the server and then open it with PDF. I couldn't reach it, but I don't think that's a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: [You cannot edit a PDF document with FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-82)

As the error message says, the source stream needs to be seekable which seems not be the case with the stream wrapper you're currently using.

You should download the file and create a [reader instance](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/the-fpdi-class/#index-4) of it:

```
$pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByString($pdfString));
```